# Executar música no programa em C

Tags: c, unix

Preciso executar uma musica durante a execução de um programa em C. No Windows podemos fazer assim - caso o arquivo esteja no mesmo diretorio do programa:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main (){

  system("start music.mp3");
  return 0;
}
```

o arquivo será executado. vocês sabem qual o equivalente em unix? pesquisei mas não consegui passar os parâmetros corretamente para as funções da biblioteca , que possivelmente faz isso: https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node22.html

Answer (score 9):

A resposta abaixo considera a utilização de um programa via linha de comando, como feito na pergunta (para o Windows). Uma outra abordagem seria utilizar uma biblioteca em C para tocar o MP3. Certamente existe alguma.

O primeiro passo é instalar um tocador de MP3 que possa ser acionado pela linha de comando. Existem vários, um deles é o mpg123.

Caso você esteja numa distribuição baseada no Debian, você pode instalar o mpg123, assim:

```
sudo apt-get install mpg123
```

Feito isso, você chama ele via linha de comando:

```
mpg123 nomeDaMusica.mp3 &
```

O & no da linha serve para que sua linha de comando não fique travada aguardando o retorno do comando.

No seu código C, você faz assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main (){

  system("mpg123 Rachmaninoff\\ -\\ Prelude\\ in\\ C-sharp\\ minor.mp3 &");
  return 0;
}
```

Note que o nome do arquivo MP3 é: Rachmaninoff - Prelude in C-sharp minor.mp3

Entretanto, para o bash lidar com espaços é necessário usar o caracter de quebra `\`.

Comment: outros player interessantes: `system("firefox rac.mp3")` system(""qvlc -q --play-and-exit 8.mp3 &")`; +1 pela escolha do preludio C#m!