# Executar música no programa em C 2

Tags: c

Obtive uma boa iluminação com essa resposta:
[Executar música no programa em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103652/executar-m%c3%basica-no-programa-em-c)

Mas quando executado o comando, não fica muito interessante como a imagem abaixo mostra:

[image: Programa em c executando com musica]

(mesmo usando o system(clear) nao resolve)

Existe alguma forma de esconder essas informações e fazer o jogo continuar normalmente, ou algum outro método mais interessante, como alguma biblioteca que oferece meios para manipulação de arquivos de áudio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela pergunta e resposta linkada vejo que está a utilizar o `mpg123`, na forma de:

```
mpg123 <arquivo_de_som>
```

Se reparar na ajuda desse utilitário vai ver que tem uma opção para executar de forma silenciosa, o `-q`. Basta então alterar o comando para:

```
mpg123 -q <arquivo_de_som>
```

Em que o `q` vem de `quiet`.

O *help* do utilitário para referência:

> ```
> usage: mpg123 [option(s)] [file(s) | URL(s) | -]
> supported options [defaults in brackets]:
>    -v    increase verbosity level       -q    quiet (don't print title)
>    -t    testmode (no output)           -s    write to stdout
>    -w f  write output as WAV file
>    -k n  skip first n frames [0]        -n n  decode only n frames [all]
>    -c    check range violations         -y    DISABLE resync on errors
>    -b n  output buffer: n Kbytes [0]    -f n  change scalefactor [32768]
>    -r n  set/force samplerate [auto]
>    -o m  select output module           -a d  set audio device
>    -2    downsample 1:2 (22 kHz)        -4    downsample 1:4 (11 kHz)
>    -d n  play every n'th frame only     -h n  play every frame n times
>    -0    decode channel 0 (left) only   -1    decode channel 1 (right) only
>    -m    mix both channels (mono)       -p p  use HTTP proxy p [$HTTP_PROXY]
>    -@ f  read filenames/URLs from f     -T get realtime priority
>    -z    shuffle play (with wildcards)  -Z    random play
>    -u a  HTTP authentication string     -E f  Equalizer, data from file
>    -C    enable control keys            --no-gapless  not skip junk/padding in mp3s
>    -?    this help                      --version  print name + version
> ```

Como vê neste *help* tem várias outras opções que podem vir a ser úteis, dependendo do seu objetivo.